# Photoshop content not moving with Artboard

Tags: adobe-photoshop, artboard

Content move along with artboard when changing position by dragging with the mouse, but changing position from properties panel only moves the artboard, not content.

[image].

Answer (score 0):

I do the same thing that the artboards are used widely on the photoshop and It does not raise such a problem in my case. It is working fine.

[image]

I think your Photoshop not working properly. So fix the Photoshop.  You need to reset the Preferences, First. (It is a dubious solution for me)

- In Windows 10, Vista or 7, the Preferences File is located at:
  Users[Username]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop\Adobe
  Photoshop (version) Settings
- In Mac,  ~Users/[Username]/Library/Preferences/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop
  (version) Settings

[Many videos can be reviewed on YouTube to reset the Preferences.]

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VXNrI6YKJIM

If it kind of didn't solve your problem, then you
can delete the Adobe Photoshop settings, (If the old settings file is not backed up and you decide to back up it up before it.)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tLvN6P7PnJU

**Note:** You should reinstall Photoshop if they don't work.